# FileNotFoundException while trying to read from SDCard

Tags: android, file, bufferedreader, sd-card

I create text file in my android phone sdcard via filebrowser in pc. Then i try to read it in android app. I get `FileNotFoundException - no such path or directory exist` error.

Here is my code

```
private String readFromFile(Context context) {

        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
            File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File file = new File(sdcard,"sample.txt");
            //Read text from file
            try {
                //File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "sample.txt");
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));//Error occurs here
                String line;
                Toast.makeText(context, "success!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    text.append(line);
                    text.append('\n');
                }
                br.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.getMessage();
                Toast.makeText(context, "Error!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //You'll need to add proper error handling here
            }
        } else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
// We can only read the media
        } else {
// Something else is wrong. It may be one of many other states, but all we need
//  to know is we can neither read nor write
        }     
        return text.toString();
    }
```

`sample.txt` is present in root directory of sdcard(i have triple checked). It has some text.

I have given read external storage permission in manifest file.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.bulsy.graphapp">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I tried running the app disconnecting form pc, then too it didn't work showing error. Might be a simple problem. Can anyone explain me where I went wrong?

Comment: Kindly check it again your interal storage not your secondary storage(sd card) that sample.txt is available or not.

Comment: it has to be in the sdcard right? while i debug BufferedReader is trying to read from `/storage/sdcard0/sample.txt` resulting `Filenotfound` exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try thing. Print the following in log and show us what the path is: `sdcard.getPath()`.

Also, use app like ES File explorer to see ur `sample.txt` file's property and get the full path. Do they match?

If the path matches, replace this:

```
File file = new File(sdcard,"sample.txt");
```

With this:

```
File file = new File("full_path_of_the_file");
```

This will help u eliminate where the problem lies.
Good luck.

Comment: the path is '/storage/sdcard0/sample.txt'

Comment: Try the following. replace `getExternalStorageDirectory()` with `getExternalStorageDirectory(null)`. see if that makes a difference

Comment: The paths were different! ES explorer says it is `/storage/sdcard1/sample.txt` ! and it worked! when i changed it as you said! cheers!

Comment: Glad it worked. Just remember to not leave it hardcoded cause the `sdcard1` part of the path can be different with different Android devices

Comment: I am getting full path of file as '/sdcard/Books/x.pdf' but sdcard.path gives '/storage/emulated/0/x.pdf'

Comment: when i use File(/sdcard/Books/x.pdf), I am getting 'file not exists', BUT when i attach pdf from downloads folder , file exists, Problem persists when i try to attach pdf file from sdcard folder, sugegstion plz